# How do I structure f# code in idiomatic manner to cater for input states (dependency)

Tags: f#

Whilst I am learning F#, I am trying to build a payroll processing engine to put in practice what I am learning.

On a high level, the payroll pipeline can be summarised as having the following steps

1. Input Earnings
2. Apply deductions on the earnings if any
3. Apply taxes on earnings after step 2
4. Apply any post tax deductions

I have got the following code that calculates the payroll for an employee

```
module Payroll=
  let calculate(payPeriods: PayPeriod list, employee:Employee, payrollEntries: Entry list )=
     // implementations, function calls go here
```

Now looking at step 3 above, you will see that we need to get tax rates (Steps have been overly simplified) to perform calculation.

Do we pass the tax rates as a parameter or is there another idiomatic way to achieve what I want to achieve.

The tax rates may be injected from a datastore.

How do I do to manage the tax part? Do inject the taxes in a parameter or I pass function that will allow me to manage this?

Comment: not too sure what the question is, there's nothing obviously wrong with your function declaration, the 'idiomatic' thing is to keep impure stuff, like getting things from a datastore outside of the calculate function, but you've done that so, whats the problem?

Comment: I tried to keep away the IO part.

I am not sure how do I get to the part where need to get the applicable taxes. Do I pass all taxes as a parameter or provide a function as a parameter that will be injected later on? What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to answer your question without any calculations, but if the question is about structuring the code in a very general way, then I can give an example vaguely inspired by your question.

For simplicity, my earnings will be just a float:

```
type Earnings = 
  { Amount : float }
```

There are also some environment parameters such as the tax and deductions:

```
type Environment = 
  { Deductions : float
    Tax : float }
```

Your core logic can be written as pure functions taking the `Environment` and `Earnings`:

```
let applyDeductions env earnings =
  { earnings with Amount = earnings.Amount - env.Deductions }
  
let applyTaxes env earnings = 
  { earnings with Amount = earnings.Amount * (1.0 - env.Tax) }
```

To read input, you could read stuff from a console or a file, but here I'll just return a constant sample:

```
let readInput () = 
  { Amount = 5000.0 }
```

Now, the main function initializes the environment (possibly from a file), reads the input and passes the `env` and the earnings to all the processing functions in a pipeline:

```
let run () = 
  let env = { Deductions = 1000.0; Tax = 0.2 }
  let earnings =
    readInput()
    |> applyDeductions env
    |> applyTaxes env
  printfn "Final: %f" earnings.Amount
```

This is way simpler than what your snippet suggests, but the structure should work pretty much the same.